# C# - LINQ to unflatten items into a hierarchical collection

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to have a LINQ statement to convert a flattened collection into a hierarchical one? I have done this with regular 'foreach' (which uses quite a few lines of code), but I hope there is some LINQ way, to make it run faster. My class looks like this:

```
public class Register
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Guid IDParent { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Register> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Flattened items will be added to a collection like this, root item has IDParent=new Guid(), a 'zero'-Guid:

```
public void InitializeCollection()
{
    ObservableCollection<Register> collectionFlat = new ObservableCollection<Register>();

    // 0 level, can be found by IDParent = {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
    collectionFlat.Add(new Register()
    {
        Caption = "A",
        ID = Guid.Parse("AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA"),
        IDParent = Guid.Parse("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"),
        Children = new ObservableCollection<Register>(),
    });

    // 1 level
    collectionFlat.Add(new Register()
    {
        Caption = "A-1",
        ID = Guid.Parse("A1A1A1A1-A1A1-A1A1-A1A1-A1A1A1A1A1A1"),
        IDParent = Guid.Parse("AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA"),
        Children = new ObservableCollection<Register>(),
    });

    // 1 level
    collectionFlat.Add(new Register()
    {
        Caption = "A-2",
        ID = Guid.Parse("A2A2A2A2-A2A2-A2A2-A2A2-A2A2A2A2A2A2"),
        IDParent = Guid.Parse("AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA"),
        Children = new ObservableCollection<Register>(),
    });

    // 2 level
    collectionFlat.Add(new Register()
    {
        Caption = "A-2-B",
        ID = Guid.Parse("A2B0A2B0-A2B0-A2B0-A2B0-A2B0A2B0A2B0"),
        IDParent = Guid.Parse("A2A2A2A2-A2A2-A2A2-A2A2-A2A2A2A2A2A2"),
        Children = new ObservableCollection<Register>(),
    });
}
```

gives this tree:

- 'A'
- -'A-1'
- -'A-2'
- --'A-2-B'

Comment: I don't know that LINQ will necessarily make it run faster - I would expect internally LINQ to use loops, depending on the task.

Comment: Why does it start flat? A sourced .txt file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ordering List with Child Items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32544814/ordering-list-with-child-items)

Comment: tofutim - yes, its a XML source file

Comment: Why don't you load directly in to a hierarchy using a composite pattern: http://www.dofactory.com/net/composite-design-pattern  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reusing my solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32545077/216074) to a very similar question, you can simply do it like this:

```
// create a mapping: id => obj
var mapping = collectionFlat.ToDictionary(x => x.ID);

// target collection
var output = new ObservableCollection<Register>();

foreach (var obj in mapping.Values)
{
    // if the parent id is an empty Guid, this is a top-level entry; otherwise
    // get the parent element from the mapping, and add to its children collection
    if (obj.IDParent == Guid.Empty)
        output.Add(x);
    else
        mapping[obj.IDParent].Children.Add(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to group your collection by IDParent and then create a dictionary where key is IDParent value of group and value is list of items in current group.

So, you will be able to go down on your hierarchy but not up.

For example, for **item** with ID = Guid.Parse("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") you need to look at YourDictionary[**item.ID**] and you will get all decendants of it.